# Copy a Hidden Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a hidden excel worksheet, but it shows error
"copy method of worksheet class failed"

```
Workbooks("FCD Alert").Activate
xPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
    Sheets("Yesterday").Activate
    'Copy the ActiveSheet to a new workbook
    Sheets("Yesterday").Copy <- This region is getting Highlighted 
    Set Destwb = ActiveWorkbook

    'Determine the Excel version and file extension/format
    With Destwb
        If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
            'You use Excel 97-2003
            FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
        Else
```

Comment: Try unhiding it before copying it? Or perhaps the sheet is protected?

Comment: Yes, you cannot copy a hidden worksheet.  You have to unhide it first.  You can hide it once the copy is complete.  Nobody should see it since your screen updating is off.

Answer (score 3):

The `.Copy` method creates a new workbook with only the copied sheet. At least one sheet must be visible in the any workbook (you can verify this independently by trying to create a new workbook with only 1 worksheet, and then try to Hide it:

[image]

So the solution should be to *unhide* it before you copy and then *hide* it in the source workbook after it has been copied.

```
Set Sourcewb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim yesterday as Worksheet
Dim wsVis as Long
Set yesterday = Sourcewb.Sheets("Yesterday")
wsVis = yesterday.Visible  ' # Get the sheet's visible state
yesterday.Visible = xlSheetVisible  ' # Make it Explicitly visible
'Copy the ActiveSheet to a new workbook
Set Destwb = yesterday.Copy
yesterday.Visible = wsVis ' # return it to its original visible state
```

Comment: ++If this causes flickering, toggle `Application.ScreenUpdating` off before, and back on after; handle run-time errors to ensure it's turned back on regardless of whether there's an error or not.